# How to read root XML tag in python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

My question follows on from another stackoverflow question:- "How to get the root node of an xml file in Python?"

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
path = 'C:\cool.xml'
et = ET.parse ( path )
root = et.getroot()
```

When I extract and print the root tag, I receive:-

```
<Element 'root' at 0x1234abcd>
```

I then want to check that the root tag has a certain title, how do I pull out just the tag name?

If I try:

```
if root == "root":
    print 'something'
```

it doesn't work, so I assume I need to convert 'root' to text or something like that? I am very new to Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`root` is an instance of the `Element` class. Any such object will have a `tag` attribute. Just use `root.tag`. Given what you say in your question, this should produce the string "root".

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to use the `tag` function to get the name of the node.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
path = 'C:\cool.xml'
et = ET.parse ( path )
root = et.getroot()

if root.tag == "root":
  print "I'm the root"
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, so simple :), just found it didn't need the () after tag. Thanks again.